# X ~ Uniform distribution

Tags: statistics

X ~ Uniform(5 , 10)

Find P( X>6 | X<9 )

I set b = 10 , a= 5 , d= 9 , and c =6 and used the formula uniform distribution formula: (d-c)/(b-a) 
I ended up getting .6 which is not right...

Comment: The vertical bar $|$ indicates a *conditional* probability: the probability that $X > 6$ *given that* $X < 9$.  You've computed the *joint* probability $P(X > 6, X < 9)$.  By definition, $P(X > 6 \mid X < 9) = \frac{P(X > 6, X < 9)}{P(X < 9)}$, so you need to divide your $0.6$ by $P(X < 9)$.

Comment: I get  P(X<9) as being (9-0)/(10-5) but that doesn't make sense.

Comment: The cdf of the uniform distribution is $F_X(x)=\frac{x-a}{b-a}$. You see your flaw ?

Comment: So the bottom should be (9-5)/(10-5) then

Comment: @user417179 That´s it.

Answer (score 1):

X ~ Uniform(5, 10)

X ~ Uniform(a, b)

$$P(X > 6 \vert X < 9) = \frac{P(X > 6 \cap X < 9)}{P(X < 9)} = \frac{P(6 < X < 9)}{P(X < 9)}=\frac{\frac{9-6}{10-5}}{\frac{9-5}{10-5}}=0.75 $$

$$P(c < X < d) = \frac{(d - c)}{(b - a)}$$
$$P(6 < X < 9) = \frac{(9 - 6)}{(10 - 5)}$$
$$P(X < 9) = \frac{(9 - 5)}{(10 - 5)}$$

"c" gets value of "a" when not present.